# Switch to last-active tab in VIM

Tags: vim, tabs

In Vim, is there a way to quickly toggle between the current tab and the last-active tab? Sort of the way <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> toggles between the current line and the last-active line. Plugins / keyboard mappings / voodoo all acceptable.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
if !exists('g:lasttab')
  let g:lasttab = 1
endif
nmap <Leader>tl :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<CR>
au TabLeave * let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()
```

Then, in normal mode, type `\tl` to swap to the tab you viewed last.

Comment: is this gvim only? mac only? I can't seem to get it working inside iterm2 on the mac (terminal vim only mode)

Comment: For UK keyboard layout, I found this more usable `nmap <c-\> :exe "tabn ".g:lasttab<CR>` .. Thanks @LucasOman

Comment: I mapped it to '<Leader>tt' but this worked like a charm. Champion answer.

Comment: I mapped that to `t<Tab>` and I love it.

Comment: You can reduce this to just key-mappings, no extra function:

`nmap <c-t><c-f> :tabn<space>1<cr>`
`nmap <c-t><c-z> :tabn<space>1<cr>:tabp<cr>`

Comment: not working in Pycharm IDE (using Vim Plugin) - this always takes you to first tab. I found using C-6 (Ctrl+6) works!

Answer (score 7):

Fix the potential issue when a tab is closed:

```
" Switch to last-active tab
if !exists('g:Lasttab')
    let g:Lasttab = 1
    let g:Lasttab_backup = 1
endif
autocmd! TabLeave * let g:Lasttab_backup = g:Lasttab | let g:Lasttab = tabpagenr()
autocmd! TabClosed * let g:Lasttab = g:Lasttab_backup
nmap <silent> <Leader>` :exe "tabn " . g:Lasttab<cr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Press `g<Tab>` in Normal mode to go to previously visited tab. This is a standard command. No need to make any changes to config.

Answer (score 3):

I use buffers and not tabs, but I am able to switch between the current and latest used buffer using `:b#`
Basics of using buffers are:

```
:e filename to open file in new buffer  
:bn to go to next buffer  
:bp to go to previous buffer  
:bd to close current buffer
```

Comment: The only reason I prefer tabs over buffers is that I can reorder tabs to group files together and find things in a large session more easily.

Comment: AFAIK, you can also use Ctrl-6 (in vimspeak it's I believe named "C-^") instead of `:b#`

Comment: `<c-^>` or `ctrl` `shift` `6`, indeed, switches to last buffer. If you type `:ls` and you have at least 2 buffers open, then you will see buffer with `%` (current buffer) to left of name and another buffer with `#` (last buffer) to left of name. So, `<c-^>` effectively does `:b#`. In fact, if you `:echo @#` you will see the previous buffer you visited. Additionally, if you `let @#="foo.bar"` it will modify the behavior of `<c-^>`, as that functionality relies on the register `'#` (`@#`). I presume the functionality of `b #` would be changed, as well, but I am not certain.

Comment: one more note: if you `:let @#="foo.bar"`, then the string `"foo.bar"` (disregarding the parentheses) must only match the path and name of a buffer that you have open. If, for example, you type `:e styles//foo.css`, then your buffer's name will be `"styles//foo.css"`, but you don't have to match the `@#` register to be `"styles//foo.css"` (although that will work). You only need to use `"styles/foo.css"`. Therefore, we can see that the buffers' names do not need to match; rather, only the preceding path names (each individually -- as if spliced on '/') and the filename need to match.

Comment: yeah well normally people use buffers *and* tabs; they serve different purposes. This is not an answer to OP's question

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution in lua for folks that uses neovim also make sure to change <A-S-b> to your favorite keybinding.

```
-- switching to last active tab
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("TabLeave",  {
    pattern = "*",
    callback = function()
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<A-S-b>', '<cmd>tabn ' .. vim.api.nvim_tabpage_get_number(0) .. '<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
    end
})
```