# vimscript call vs. execute

Tags: vim, viml

In vimscript, what is the difference between `call` and `execute`?  In what scenarios / use cases should I use one vs the other?

(Disclaimer, I am aware of the extensive online help available within vim - I am seeking a concise answer to this specific question).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the experience of writing my own plugins and reading the code of others:

**`:call`** is for calling functions, e.g.:

```
function! s:foo(id)
    execute 'buffer' a:id
endfunction

let target_id = 1
call foo(target_id)
```

**`:execute`** is used for two things:

1. Construct a string and evaluate it. This is often used to pass arguments to commands:

   ```
   execute 'source' fnameescape('l:path')
   ```
2. Evaluate the return value of a function (arguably the same):

   ```
   function! s:bar(id)
       return 'buffer ' . a:id
   endfunction

   let target_id = 1
   execute s:bar(target_id)
   ```

Answer (score 30):

- `:call`: Call a function.
- `:exec`: Executes a string as an Ex command. 
  It has the similar meaning of `eval`(in `javascript`, `python`, etc)

---

For example:

```
function! Hello()
   echo "hello, world"
endfunction

call Hello()

exec "call Hello()"
```

Comment: In what scenarios would I want to use one vs. the other? Or is execute only for when you need to programmatically compose the command to execute?

Comment: You can build a command dynamically, and `exec` it. However you can only call a function by name.

Comment: You might want to show an example of building an ex command using exec and string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

You may see `call` as first evaluate the expression and then discard the result. So only the side effects are useful.

## Long answer

Define:

```
function! Foo()
    echo 'echoed'
    return 'returned'
endfunction
```

Call:

```
:call Foo()
```

Output:

```
echoed
```

Execute:

```
:execute Foo()
```

Output:

```
echoed
EXXX: Not an editor command: returned
```

Execute:

```
:silent let foo = Foo()
:echo foo
```

Output:

```
returned
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Switch to last-active tab in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119754/switch-to-last-active-tab-in-vim)

for example

:exe "tabn ".g:lasttab

Where
g:lasttab is a global variable to store the current tab number
and that number is concatenated with "tabnext" to switch e.g to tab number 3
(If g:lasttab e.g. contains '3' for example)

That whole string >"tabn ".g:lasttab< 
is evaluated and executed by VIM's exec command.

HTH?